# Как вызвать хук при определенном условии?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, условия, хук

Всем привет. Интернет-магазин на woocommerce. Есть хук `add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array(&$this, 'mad_woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart_form'), 30);`, который вызывает мою функцию `mad_woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart_form`. В ней есть условия `if-else` при выполнении которых я хочу вызвать в ней еще один хук(-и) `add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array(&$this, 'woocommerce_shop_before_process'), 31);`, который не зарегистрирован, но функция имеется. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно учитывать последовательность выполнения хуков. Вот пример, т.к. init идёт раньше чем wp код выполняется.

```
class MyTestClass {

    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'firstMethod']);
    }

    public function firstMethod()
    {
        $test = rand(0,1);
        if($test){
            add_action('wp', [__CLASS__, 'secondMethod']);
        }else{
            add_action('wp', [__CLASS__, 'thirdMethod']);
        }
    }

    public static function secondMethod()
    {
        echo "Second Method";
    }

    public static function thirdMethod()
    {
        echo "Third Method";
    }
}

new MyTestClass();
```